# OCRing badly compressed JPG with numbers using Tesseract and OpenCV C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm having a few troubles OCRing this image using tesseract and openCV (.net/ C#)

PasswordBox:

[image]

At first, only empty lines with this white image, but then I applied greyscale and tried inversing colors. result was better.

then I used openCV methods to SmoothGaussian and SmoothMedian (just with 1 as parameter), it was nicer but still not all characters are recognized :

```
n IHHIEI 5

4 7
```

a few numbers are recognized.

I also tried to split by three lines (30 pixel height), results were worse (this is only the first line)...

```
[9| I2l l‘ll
```

I see the 9, the 2 between these I and L, but the 1 on this line isn't : l‘ll

the code i use is the next one :

```
   try
    {
        Bitmap imageBMP = ConvertToBitmap(cheminFichier.ToString());

    //option par défaut pour les couleurs ?

    imageBMP = GrayScale(imageBMP);

    if (isGreyScale == true)
    {
        for (int y = 0; (y <= (imageBMP.Height - 1)); y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; (x <= (imageBMP.Width - 1)); x++)
            {
                Color inv = imageBMP.GetPixel(x, y);
                inv = Color.FromArgb(255, (255 - inv.R), (255 - inv.G), (255 - inv.B));
                imageBMP.SetPixel(x, y, inv);
            }
        }
    }

    imageBMP.Save(tempDir.ToString() + "\\img.png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

    Image<Gray, Byte> temp = new Image<Gray, Byte>((Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile((tempDir.ToString() + "\\img.png")));
    //Image<Gray, Byte> temp = new Image<Gray, Byte>((Bitmap)Bitmap.Fr);
    temp = temp.SmoothGaussian(1);
    temp = temp.SmoothMedian(1);
    temp = temp.SmoothBlur(240, 90);


    //these are how i separate the result in 3 images
    Bitmap img1 = cropAtRect(temp.Bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 0, 240, 30));
    img1.Save(tempDir.ToString() + "\\1.png");

    Bitmap img2 = cropAtRect(temp.Bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 30, 240, 30));
    img2.Save(tempDir.ToString() + "\\2.png");

    Bitmap img3 = cropAtRect(temp.Bitmap, new Rectangle(0, 60, 240, 30));
    img3.Save(tempDir.ToString() + "\\3.png");


    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("erreur pendant la conversion/copie du fichier image(s)." +         ex.ToString());
    }
```

all these png are stored in a tempdir, then i read and convert every png in that dir and concatenate the text

```
 using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(@"./tessdata", "fra", EngineMode.Default))
            {
                //Console.ReadLine();
                string fichierDeSortie = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "output.txt";
                string retourFichier = "";
                foreach (FileInfo fichier in infoDir.GetFiles())
                {

                    if (fichier.Extension.ToString().ToUpper() == ".PNG")
                    {


                        string actualFilePAth = fichier.FullName.ToString();
                        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Bitmap.FromFile(actualFilePAth);
                        //on peut desactiver le bitmap avec l'option -B

                        //convertir en pix to image
                        //System.Drawing.Bitmap tmppage = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(actualFilePAth));

                        if (BitmapActive == true)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\r\n Bitmap Activé !\r\n");
                            using (var page = engine.Process(bmp))
                            {
                                var text = page.GetText();
                                retourFichier = retourFichier + text.ToString();
                                //Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Tesseract.Pix pix = Tesseract.PixConverter.ToPix(bmp);
                            using (var page = engine.Process(pix))
                            {
                                var text = page.GetText();
                                retourFichier = retourFichier + text.ToString();
                                //Console.WriteLine(text.ToString());
                            }
                        }
                            Console.WriteLine("decodé : " + fichier.FullName.ToString());
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(fichierDeSortie, retourFichier);
                        //fichier.Delete();
                    }

                }
            }                  
            Console.WriteLine("Conversion du pdf en png OK.");
```

I notice some "compression marks"(small pixelated bubles from compressing a JPG) around the numbers that are not recognized. they will always be numbers.

What can I do to get better results? I'm running in circles trying to do stuff with openCV without much luck... tesseract seems ok on a lot of pdf i convert everyday.

Thanks in advance, IVAN

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: sure, code is a bit complex, do i edit the answer or repond in here with the code i use ?

Comment: i added the code i use, i am going to cut every cell (30 pix by 30 pix). try ocring each to see. if not i will cut the inside of those 30pix boxes just to extract the number from what i consider max height and width of the number. will post the results.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract is very sensitive to noise so you've to clean up the image as much as you can. The following code is in Python but you can easily port it to C#.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import pytesseract

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = cv2.imread('image.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    ret,binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY|cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

    mask = cv2.bitwise_not(binary)

    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (3,3))
    mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel, iterations = 3)

    (rows,cols) = image.shape[:2]

    contours = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[1]

    for cnt in contours:
        (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(cnt)
        if w < cols/4 and h < rows/4:
            cv2.drawContours(mask, [cnt], -1, 0, -1)

    binary[mask == 255] = 255

    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(binary, lang='eng',config='--tessdata-dir /tesseract/tessdata/data --psm 6 --oem 2')
    print(text)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well OpenCV+Tesseract can be very powerful if used correctly. What you are trying to achieve can be summarised in following manner.

OpenCV

- make image grayscale
- apply threshold on grayscale image
- invert the image so that text is white and background is black

  - if you are trying to detect individual words instead of character dilate your inverted mat with a structuring element(horizontal gap, 1)
- findContours(mat ,contours, structuring element,anchor)
- for every contour get a Rect rect=boundingRect(countour[i]), now you have location of desired text/ pixel groupings
- you can do mat(rect) to extract specific image portion

Tesseract

- first download eng.traineddata best from github
- once you initiate tesseract if you are working with a specific char set, say numbers only you have two variables `tessedit_char_blacklist` ( enforced , so all alphabets and special char should be here ) , `tessedit_char_whitelist`(suggestion,put numeric values here)
- also alignment matters alot ,so if possible just crop all the text that should be in one line and make them a linear mat( hconcat() will help ). before you OCR it.

I do my development in C++ so you need to find out the equivalent functions for your preferred language.